# MySQL: How to index my table to optimize this query?

Tags: mysql

My table contains history of values relating to objects, it looks like:

```
create table History (
    object_id  bigint  NOT NULL,
    value      int     NOT NULL,
    date       bigint  NOT NULL
);
```

How can I index it to optimize following query:

```
select * from History
    where object_id = ? and date < ?
    order by date desc
    limit ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create composite index `object_id + date`

```
CREATE INDEX object_id_date ON History(object_id, `date`);
```

Comment: @pst: nope, with conditions like `key_part1 = const AND key_part2 < const` the only order that makes sense is `key_part1 + key_part2`, as long as range condition prevents of further using of right index part. In this particular case `oid + date` covers both `WHERE` condition and `ORDER BY` (bacause of left-most part is constant)

Comment: thanks, does it optimize all 4 parts of my query? is any of them left unoptimized which i should find another way to optimize it?

Comment: @JohnS: It optimizes `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`. Not sure what other 2 parts you're talking about. `LIMIT` - cannot be optimized, it is just limit. And `SELECT *` is not optimized - because it is `*` there

Comment: thanks, just another naive question: do you think this is an optimized structure to store and query history of values in a RDB when there are too many objects and history records? any better design pattern you know about?

Comment: @JohnS Is there a reason to do otherwise [now or in the immediate future]? :)

Comment: @pst :) i'm just trying to make sure i'm doing it correctly and my code is scalable. i'm not good at DBs.

Comment: @JohnS: "any better design pattern you know about?" --- to be clear - you haven't explained the task. So we don't know what you're actually solving

Comment: @zerkms, thanks, i will try to write down a short description of my task and ask it as a new question.